# Why does this async / await code generate "...not all code paths return a value"?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

Hopefully this isn't a repeat, but there are 5000+ questions here with "not all code paths return a value"!

Quite simply, why does this method with a non-generic implementation compile just fine:

```
    public static async Task TimeoutAfter(this Task task, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        if (task == await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout)))
            await task;
        else
            throw new TimeoutException();
    }
```

while this attempt to make the method generic generates a `Return state missing` / ...`not all code paths return a value` warning / error?:

```
    public static async Task<T> TimeoutAfter<T>(this Task<T> task, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        if (task == await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout)))
            await task;
        else
            throw new TimeoutException();
    }
```

Comment: @L.B \*"*should* return `Task` and ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The non-generic `Task` type is somewhat equivalent to an awaitable void method. Just like a void method, you *can't* return anything from a method that has a return type of `Task`, which is why the first example compiles. The second example, though, expects a return value of the generic type and you aren't providing one in the path where you await another call.

Quoting from the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) on the `async` keyword, specifically about return types.

> You use Task if no meaningful value is returned when the method is
>   completed. That is, a call to the method returns a Task, but when the
>   Task is completed, any await expression that's awaiting the Task
>   evaluates to void.

Comment: My understanding is that the value of the await expression is *applied* to the return value, so it's not equivalent to returning Void, however await in itself is `System.Void`.

Comment: That's true that the method does implicitly return a `Task` that you can then await. It's equivalent to void in that you are not allowed to return a value from the method yourself and nothing can be assigned as the result of awaiting that method. In the case of `Task<T>`, the `T` you return will then be assignable from an await (e.g. `var value = await SomeCall();`).

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.  It makes total sense now, but initially the layer of abstraction of the construct was throwing me off.

Answer (score 8):

In the second example you gave you didn't return anything. (See Chris Hannon's answer for why).

```
public static async Task<T> TimeoutAfter<T>(this Task<T> task, int millisecondsTimeout) {
    if (task == await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout)))
        return await task; // return the Task of T
    else
        throw new TimeoutException();
}
```

In addition to what @ChrisHannon said, from the [await documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx).

> ... if `await` is applied to the result of a method call that returns a `Task<TResult>`, then the type of the await expression is `TResult`. If `await` is applied to the result of a method call that returns a `Task`, then the type of the await expression is `void`. ...

Comment: Thanks, David.  I appreciate the example.